# Execute private method in C# interactive window

Tags: c#, private, c#-interactive

Does exist any escamotage to execute a **private** method from the C# interactive window?

That is, suppose I have a simple class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
    public static string SayBye()
    {
        return "Bye";
    }
}
```

In the Visual studio I can click on "Initialize Interactive with project" and then I can access and call `SayBye()` method like in the following example:

```
> MyClass.SayBye()
"Bye"
```

Is there any way to access also `SayHello()` private method? This would be useful during development for test purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `> MyClass.SayHello()` might actually work in the interactive window, have you tried it?

If it doesn't, you can execute `SayHello` the same way you would do if you were trying to execute it via normal code - with reflection. You might write something that looks like this into the interactive prompt:

```
typeof(MyClass)
  .GetMethod("SayHello", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
  .Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```

You'll need to change the binding flags and Invoke method parameters depending on where the method is. (`BindingFlags.Instance` vs `BindingFlags.Static` etc)

**Alternate**:

If working with an instance object (not static), there exists several implementations out there which use the magic of `dynamic` to exposes private members. If you do a google search you can find an implementation of this (or write one yourself).

That would allow you to write code like this:

```
(new PrivateExposerObject(myClass)).SayHello();
```

Comment: What you propose works, thank you! But it is not very practical. 

After having read other questions similar to mine, I refactored my code and I will use your solution just exceptionally.

Thanks, g.

Comment: The second part of your answer is really a non-answer since you don't offer any links and just using `dynamic` by itself won't let you call private methods.

Comment: easily a google search or a little bit of custom code away - `PrivateExposerObject` is just an example of what could be built. or like i said, google https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidebb/2010/01/18/use-c-4-0-dynamic-to-drastically-simplify-your-private-reflection-code/ or https://igoro.com/archive/use-c-dynamic-typing-to-conveniently-access-internals-of-an-object/